# Can't install software in Debian 6

Tags: debian, apt, source, aptitude

I installed `Debian 6 Squeez` on my virtual machine and I can't install software using `aptitude` or `apt-get`. This is my `sources.list` file:

```
root@debian:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20120512-13:45]/ squeeze contrib main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20120512-13:45]/ squeeze contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib
# deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib
root@debian:/etc/apt#
```

I tried commenting the `cdrom` lines, I also tried to add some sources I found on the net but none of them are working. Can anyone tell me why the default `sources.list` file doesn't have the appropriate configuration so I can easily `aptitude install lftp` for example? What can I do to install software from their repositories?

Comment: Have you tried exec: `apt-get update` after save changes at sources.list file?

Comment: can anyone tell me why the downvotes? :) maybe next time i won't make the same mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see, you don't have the main (non-updates, non-security) repositories (I wonder why). This is how should look your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian oldstable main contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
```

After this, you should run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now you can install the `lftp` package with just:

```
sudo apt-get install lftp
```

Comment: This is the default sources.list after installing debian...I also wonder why

Comment: Added the lines but `lftp` is still not found. I also get `Err http://archive.debian.org oldstable/main i386 Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
`, `Err http://archive.debian.org oldstable/contrib i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
` and `W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
8B48AD6246925553
` after `sudo aptitude update`

Comment: yes, but `No candidate version found for debian-keyring`...since I don't have the right sources :( Can anyone tell me why aren't the default sources ok?

Comment: It can't find the address: `Connecting to ftp.us.debian.org|128.61.240.89|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-08-14 16:07:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Answer (score 0):

Comment out each "deb cdrom:" line, and add the line

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze main contrib
```

to your sources.list, then

```
$ sudo aptitude update
$ sudo aptitude install [package name]
```

If you're trying to install a package from Testing/Experimental, add

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main
```

to your sources.list, then grab a package using

```
$ sudo aptitude update
$ sudo aptitude -t experimental install [package name]
```

Comment: Oh, I was looking for the `lftp` package and I couldn't find it, where can I find the `testing` and other repositories? And why aren't they in the `sources.list` file? Is there any chance to find `lftp` there? I can find it on `packages.debian.org` but not on the repos, why is that?

Comment: @cepkos he doesn't even have the main repositories in his `sources.list`